# Error "No matching unique or primary key for this column-list" con un PK compuesto

Tags: sql, oracle

Realizando un trabajo me he encontrado con el error:

> DAN_FACTURA(FACTURA), "No matching unique or primary key for this
>   column-list"

Revisando mi tabla `DAN_FACTURA` revisé la declaración y, según lo que sé, tengo correcta mi sintaxis para la Primary Key en esta tabla. Sin embargo, a la hora de referenciarla, no me lo permite.

Estoy seguro que es un error de sintaxis en algún lado pero le he dado por horas y no logro encontrarlo.

```
CREATE TABLE DAN_FACTURA
    (
    FACTURA     NUMBER(10),
    SUCURSAL    NUMBER(5)  CONSTRAINT FK_SUC REFERENCES
    DAN_SUCURSAL(SUCURSAL),
    FECHA       DATE,
    IMPUESTO    NUMBER(5,2) CONSTRAINT CK_IMP CHECK (IMPUESTO >= 0),
    TOTAL_SIN_IMP   NUMBER(12,2) CONSTRAINT CK_TOT_SIMP CHECK (TOTAL_SIN_IMP >0),
    TOTAL_CON_IMP   NUMBER(12,2) CONSTRAINT CK_TOT_CIMP CHECK (TOTAL_CON_IMP >0),
    CLIENTE     NUMBER(10) CONSTRAINT FK_FAC_CLI REFERENCES
    DAN_CLIENTE(CLIENTE),
    FORMA_PAGO  CHAR(2) CONSTRAINT CK_FAC_FOR CHECK(FORMA_PAGO IN('C','E','TC','TD')),
    EMPLEADO    NUMBER(10) CONSTRAINT FK_FAC_EMP REFERENCES
    DAN_EMPLEADO(EMPLEADO),
    CONSTRAINT PK_FAC PRIMARY KEY(FACTURA,SUCURSAL)
    );

    CREATE TABLE DAN_DETALLE_FACTURA
    (
    FACTURA     NUMBER(10) CONSTRAINT FK_FACT REFERENCES
    DAN_FACTURA(FACTURA),
    SUCURSAL    NUMBER(5) CONSTRAINT FK_FAC_SUC REFERENCES
    DAN_SUCURSAL(SUCURSAL),
    ARTICULO    NUMBER(10) CONSTRAINT FK_FAC_ART REFERENCES
    DAN_ARTICULO(ARTICULO),
    PRECIO      NUMBER(10,2) CONSTRAINT CK_PRECIO CHECK(PRECIO >0),
    DESCUENTO   NUMBER(3,2) CONSTRAINT  CK_DESC CHECK(DESCUENTO>=0),
    CANTIDAD    NUMBER(5) CONSTRAINT    CK_CANT CHECK(CANTIDAD >=0),
    TOTAL_POR_LINEA NUMBER(10,2) CONSTRAINT CK_TOT_LINEA CHECK(TOTAL_POR_LINEA>0),
    CONSTRAINT PK_DETALLE PRIMARY KEY(FACTURA,SUCURSAL,ARTICULO)
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me temo que vas a tener que añadir una **restricción** de unicidad sobre el campo FACTURA de la tabla DAN_FACTURA, ya que de otra manera la referencia externa en el campo FACTURA de la tabla DAN_DETALLE_FACTURA estaría definida ambiguamente y podría "devolver" varias filas.

Comment: Hola Oscar, muchas gracias. Al parecer funciona perfectamente, justo lo que necesitaba!